# Hbase vs Google Bigtable: scan for large number of rows

Tags: hbase, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

I am trying to a Scan with a start and end row on Bigtable.
The elements between the scan are around 100K.
I want to get them in batches which I was able to do in HBase with using `setCaching(500)`.

In Bigtable, it seems `setCaching` is ignored and it tries to get the entire resultset in 1 RPC. How can it be achieved similar to HBase?

I am using Java driver `bigtable-hbase-1.1` and version `1.0.0-pre3`

Bigtable configuration:

```java
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("google.bigtable.buffered.mutator.throttling.enable", "false");
conf.set("google.bigtable.rpc.timeout.ms", "1500000");
conf.set("google.bigtable.grpc.read.partial.row.timeout.ms","1500000");
conf.set("google.bigtable.long.rpc.timeout.ms", "1500000");
conf.set("google.bigtable.grpc.retry.deadlineexceeded.enable", "false");
conf.set("google.bigtable.buffered.mutator.max.inflight.rpcs", "500");
conf.set("google.bigtable.bulk.max.row.key.count", "500");

Configuration conff =  BigtableConfiguration.configure(conf,projectID,instanceID);
connection = BigtableConfiguration.connect(conff);
```

Scanner configuration:

```java
byte[] start = "prefix".getbytes() ;
byte[] end =  Bytes.add("prefix".getbytes(),(byte))0xff);
Scan scan = new Scan(start, end);
```

Expected number of rows to come out is of the order of 100Ks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t have to worry about batching when reading rows. The Bigtable responses get streamed and are backpressure aware. We rely on GRPC to buffer chunks of the stream as well. 
Here is a link to an introduction about GRPC streaming:
https://grpc.io/docs/guides/concepts.html#server-streaming-rpc

Would mind trying out this sample code and let me know if it works (ie. no deadline exceeded errors). If the sample code works, please modify it to scan your own data and make sure that it still works. If something doesn't, please let me know.

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.google.cloud.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>row-write-read-example</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud.bigtable</groupId>
      <artifactId>bigtable-hbase-1.x</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0-pre3</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

java:

```
import com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.BigtableConfiguration;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HColumnDescriptor;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HConstants;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HTableDescriptor;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableName;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Admin;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.BufferedMutator;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Connection;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ResultScanner;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Table;

public class WriteReadTest {
  private static final String PROJECT_ID = "<YOUR_PROJECT_ID>";
  private static final String INSTANCE_ID = "<YOUR_INSTANCE_ID>";
  private static final String TABLE_ID = "<YOUR_NONEXISTENT_TABLE>";
  private static final String FAMILY = "cf";

  private static final TableName TABLE_NAME = TableName.valueOf(TABLE_ID);

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try(Connection connection = BigtableConfiguration.connect(PROJECT_ID, INSTANCE_ID);
        Admin admin = connection.getAdmin()) {

      // Setup
      admin.createTable(
          new HTableDescriptor(TABLE_NAME)
              .addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor(FAMILY))
      );

      try {
        // Write the rows
        populateTable(connection, 2_000_000);

        // Read the rows
        readFullTable(connection);
      } finally {
        admin.disableTable(TABLE_NAME);
        admin.deleteTable(TABLE_NAME);
      }

    }
  }

  private static void populateTable(Connection connection, int rowCount) throws IOException {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int buckets = 100;
    int maxWidth = Integer.toString(buckets).length();

    try(BufferedMutator bufferedMutator = connection.getBufferedMutator(TABLE_NAME)) {
      for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        String prefix = String.format("%0" + maxWidth + "d", i % buckets);
        String key = prefix + "-" + String.format("%010d", i);
        String value = "value-" + key;

        Put put = new Put(key.getBytes())
            .addColumn(
                FAMILY.getBytes(),
                HConstants.EMPTY_BYTE_ARRAY,
                value.getBytes()
            );

        bufferedMutator.mutate(put);
      }
    }

    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.printf("Populated table in %d secs, writing %d rows\n", (endTime - startTime) / 1000, rowCount);
  }

  private static void readFullTable(Connection connection) throws IOException {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    int count = 0;
    try(Table table = connection.getTable(TABLE_NAME);
        ResultScanner scanner = table.getScanner(new Scan("0".getBytes(), "z".getBytes()))) {

      for(Result row = scanner.next(); row != null; row = scanner.next()) {
        count++;
      }
    }

    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.printf("Scanned table in %d secs, reading %d rows\n", (endTime - startTime) / 1000, count);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have kept long RPC timeout of 5 minutes and still getting DEADLINE exceeded error. for just 100k rows ?

Comment: Is there a way to tune the buffer chunk size ? May be it is too small .
In my case since client is in singapore and bigtable in taiwan a single round trip takes ~50 ms

Comment: Or is it because Bigtable first get the entire result on server and then stream it to the client. I guess then getting the entire result-set could be time consuming may be ?

Comment: I don’t think setting a deadline does what you want in the case of streaming responses. When streaming a deadline would not only require the server to send the entire response but for your client code to consume it.

Comment: Oops, posted too early, instead you want to set a timeout how long it takes a single row to be read and you can configure it using google.bigtable.grpc.read.partial.row.timeout.ms. You can find more configuration options here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-client/blob/master/bigtable-hbase-parent/bigtable-hbase/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/bigtable/hbase/BigtableOptionsFactory.java

Comment: READ_BUFFER_SIZE default value is 60 rows. 
What exactly does this parameter means. Does it means it sends 60 rows in a stream ?

Comment: My apologies, I forgot about the scanner buffer.  There are 2 levels of buffering: raw chunks at the grpc level and complete rows at the scanner level.

Comment: The scanner level buffer will be refilled as you consume the results from the scanner. However please note that unlike Hbase , the grpc deadline is measured from the first row in stream to the very last row in the stream. So the buffer doesn’t affect deadline exceeded errors. Would it be possible for you to link to an example of how you are reading the results and configuring the client?

Comment: updated in question. The issue is scan gets deadline exceeded when expected resultset is huge.

Comment: Would mind trying out this sample code: http://dpaste.com/0A2B08K? Let me know if it works, and if it does, please modify it to scan your own data